# Futura Font in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts

We are trying to use Futura Std Light Condensed font in HTML. The Font is installed in our system but it is not being rendered in HTML.

However when we are using Futura Std Condensed in HTML it is getting rendered properly.

We are able to see both the fonts from Notepad/Word however it is not being rendered in HTML.

We are using inline style in HTML to use the font:
`style="font-family:'Futura Std Condensed Light'"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <span style="font-family:'Futura Std Condensed';font-weight:bold;">Sample Text</span> 
    <br/>
    <span style="font-family:'Futura Std Condensed Light'">Sample Text</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you converted the fonts to the correct formats and included them in a `@font-face` declaration?

Comment: Please add the minimal ammount of code to recreate your problem in your question please.

Comment: Updated Post with sample code. We are not using @font face. Inline style is working for the first font but not for the 2nd one.

Comment: you will be the only one to see the correct font (as they are local to your machine) if you don't include them using `@font-face`. Is this webpage only going to be viewed locally on your machine?

Comment: Currently i am not able to see from my Local machine itself. The problem is Futura Std Condensed is working but Futura Std Condensed Light is not working. Both are installed in local system.

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking some CSS there. Also some header data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <title>Kind of required</title>
  <style>
    /* preferably, of course, this is a <link> instead */
    @font-face {
      font-family: Futura;
      src: local('Futura Std');
    }
    span {
      font-family: Futura;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Sample Text</span> 
</body>
</html>
```

If you want more than "just load the font for me", relying on system fonts is going to give you a bad time (as it is unpredictable what the system will need you to specify for name): pack the fonts as WOFF (because every browser supports that) and then point to the WOFF files:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Futura;
  src: url('.../FuturaStdRegular.woff') format("WOFF");
  font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Futura;
  src: url('.../FuturaStdLight.woff') format("WOFF");
  font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Futura;
  src: url('.../FuturaStdBoldItalic.woff') format("WOFF");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
...etc...
```

Same family, different font resources depending on the variant, weight, style, etc. properties used later on.

(Of course it goes without saying that if this ever leaves your own computer, make sure you have legal permission to use these fonts, but let's say it anyway)